# Crystal Reports, Suppressing a details based on condition

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress

I have a report that has 7 details sections. One of the details is a disclaimer that prints on the back of the letter. What I need is to have that disclaimer print only on 3 of the six remaining details sections. The six remaining details print based on their letter type and are identified by P 1-3 and S 1-3. I need to have the disclaimer print only on the P letters.

I was hoping there was a formula similar to

if {RENFUP.RFBAIT} = "S" then *suppress details g*

I just don't know how to accomplish the *suppress details g* portion of the formula. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppression formula would be:

`{RENFUP.RFBAIT}="S"`

A suppression formula doesn't need the IF or THEN part, just a condition that will return a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The formula works fine except for one issue, the last letter in the report only shows the body of one of the "S" letters. No Page header or footer or the strings they contain.

Comment: so, the last detail section is on its own page, but w/o the PH and PF sections?

Comment: Yes. The report is bringing up the correct detail section for that letter, just nothing else.

Comment: do you have any suppression logic in the PH/PF?

Comment: In both the PH and PF, Suppress (No Drill-Down) if pagenumber = TotalPageCount then True

Comment: that logic (in the PH and PF) is what is causing the issue.  does it there for a reason?

Comment: It's there so that the PH and PF doesn't print on the back of the letter with the disclaimer.

Comment: you should probably incorporate the {RENFUP.RFBAIT}="S" logic in the RH/RF logic.  maybe (PageNumber=TotalPageCount AND {RENFUP.RFBAIT}<>"S")?

Comment: Awesome! You are the man Craig! Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.